# Angular Standalone Pipe with Storybook: NG0302: The pipe could not be found in the component

Tags: angular, typescript, storybook, angular-storybook

Got the task to include a standalone pipe in Storybook. My Pipe as simple as:
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

```js
@Pipe({
    name: 'shortpipe',
    standalone: true,
})
export class ShortPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any): any {
        return 'hello';
    }
}
```

Even my Storybook story is not that complicated:

```js
const meta: Meta<any> = {
    title: 'Title of my fantastic story',
    render: () => ({
        template: `<p>{{'22222' | shortpipe}}</p>`,
    }),
};

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<any>;

export const Default: Story = {
    render: (args) => ({
        moduleMetadata: [
            {
                imports: [ShortPipe],
            },
        ],
        template: `<p>{{'22222' | shortpipe}}</p>`,
    }),
};
```

However I got the error:
`NG0302: The pipe 'shortpipe' could not be found in the 'StorybookWrapperComponent' component. Verify that it is declared or imported in this module. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0302`

Angular:  15.0.2

@storybook/angular: 6.5.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer already, the issue was only placing moduleMetadata import to the wrong place. Moving it up to the decorators array fixed it:

```js
export const Default: Story = {
   decorators: [
       moduleMetadata({
           imports: [ShortPipe],
       }),
   ],
   render: (args) => ({
       template: `<p>{{'22222' | shortpipe}}</p>`,
   }),
};
```